# tcp retransmission queue

Tags: networking, tcp, timer

I found an interesting question about retransmission queue on TCP, I've been reading [this](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.475.1.124/1/)
, I can see from this article that there are so many timers on TCP, but what I don't get is how they all sync with each other, for example when when the messages is sent, it's placed on a retransmission queue, and a retransmission timer will check this queue when the time reached 0 on the queue to be retransmitted. 
Is this queue a Queue data structure? and it seems to be that two TCP function will check this queue, the first one is the retransmission queue retransmit the message, and the synak timer that delete the packet that has been been delivered successfully, in this case there must be some sync mechanism between those timers as they access the same queue, right?

Can you any one help understand how this works?

Comment: Accept some more answers please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong conception of timers. It's not an application. These are operating system timers: there is no issue about keeping them in synchronization. I think you have the wrong conception of queues too: I don't know exactly what you mean by 'is this queue a Queue data structure'? The question doesn't really make sense. A queue is a queue. In this case again it is a kernel queue. How it is implemented isn't any concern of anybody except the kernel authors.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, my question is how can two timers update the same queue, for example if one time reached 0 then the retransmission timer will update the queue, what if SYNACK timer received ack and now is trying to update the retransmission queue as well. I'm not sure who's gonna remove the ACKed packet from the retransmission queue, is it the SYNACK timer or something else. please share any document that could make get this right?

Comment: @JackJordan I suggest a good look at [RFC 793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt).

Comment: Thanks EJP for the link, so quoting form it "When the TCP transmits a segment containing data, it puts a copy on a retransmission queue and starts a timer; when the acknowledgment for that data is received, the segment is deleted from the queue. If the acknowledgment is not received before the timer runs out, the segment is retransmitted." Does that mean that there is a timer set for each packet? and what if sync is received and at the same the same time timer reached 0, what will happen then?

Comment: BTW, I'm talking/asking about Linux implementation

Comment: And another question, does tcp wait for a single packet to be ACKed to send the next one or send multiple packets and wait multiple ACKed ?

Comment: @JackJordan If a packet is acknowledged in time it isn't retransmitted. I don't see any mystery there. Yes that implies a timer per packet (more correctly per segment). TCP sends as much as it can, limited by the current receive window, and it also practices selective acknowledgement.